# how to get data from javascript ajax from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a script with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button;
    var line;
    var inputs;
    var params = {};
    var updatefield;
    $('button.update').click(function () {
        button = $(this);
        params['button'] = button.val();
        line = button.closest('.line');
        updatefield = line.find('td.resultFromGet');
        inputs = line.find('input');
        inputs.each(function (id, item) {
            switch($(item).attr('type')){
                case 'checkbox':{
                    params[$(item).attr('name')] = new Array($(item).is(':checked'));
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    params[$(item).attr('name')] = new Array($(item).attr('value'));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        //alert(JSON.stringify(params, null, 4));
        $.get( 'core/ajax/correct_exec.php', params )
            .done(function (data){
                if(data == '1'){
                    $(updatefield).html('UPDATE_RECORD_SUCCESS');
                } else {
                    $(updatefield).html( data );
                }
            });
    });
});
```

The page I am getting is doing `echo '1';` from PHP in case of success. 
I try to test this with `data == 1` but it doesn't work even though it is a success. In fact, it sends me `$(updatefield).html( data );` which is `1`. So why can't it just print `UPDATE_RECORD_SUCCESS`?

Comment: `updatefield` is already a jQuery object, so you can just do: `updatefield.html('UPDATE_RECORD_SUCCESS');`

Comment: try `console.log(data);`

Comment: also try `console.log(typeof data)`

Comment: console.log($(updatefield).length); so that you know if it exists.
But still id recommend to use chrome and put a breaking point on that line of code: 
if(data == '1')

Comment: how can I do that? I never used any debug tool for javascript, only try and errors. Do you have a link where I can see how to do breaking point and use chrome for that. In fact, I didn't even know it was possible so I guess learning that will help me so much in finding my errors in the future :).

Comment: just press F12 and a debug tool will appear at the bottom. choose console on the tabs and you'll see console.log messages (and any other errors) there

Comment: also please provide your relevant PHP code as well, so we can pinpoint the problem rather than guessing what it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` response is coming with white space, if you use `trim()` function  something like this, then `if` condition should be executed.

```
if(data.trim() == '1'){
     $('#updatefield').html('UPDATE_RECORD_SUCCESS'); //this should be executed
} else {
  $('#updatefield').html( data );
}
```

Here you can see the space with `data` in chrome debugger.

[image]

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to see this in chrome debugger? I used a console.log(data) but I don't see the little arrow showing there is a return at the EOL.

Comment: For this you will have to use breakpoint to line `if(data == '1'){`, for information about breakpoint see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints.